# ¿"Scope" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

[Debatiendo con Carlos Alejo en Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/estamos-de-enhorabuena-estado-efervescente-del-sitio-y-c%C3%B3mo-seguir-creciendo/2507?noredirect=1#comment3979_2507) fui a utilizar la palabra inglesa *scope*. En concreto, quería utilizar la palabra para definir el ámbito de trabajo de una pregunta: qué debía cubrir y qué no.

Me quedé pensando cuál podría ser una buena palabra para designar este concepto, *scope*, que el diccionario inglés define como:

> [**scope**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scope?s=t)
>   noun
>   1. **extent or range of view, outlook, application, operation, effectiveness, etc.**: *an investigation of wide scope.*
>   2. space for movement or activity; opportunity for operation: *to give one's fancy full scope.*
>   3. extent in space; a tract or area.
>   4. length: *a scope of cable.*
>   5. **aim or purpose**.
>   6. Linguistics, Logic. the range of words or elements of an expression over which a modifier or operator has control: *In “old men and women,” “old” may either take “men and women” or just “men” in its scope.*
>   7. (used as a short form of microscope, oscilloscope, periscope, radarscope, riflescope, telescopic sight, etc.)

Por ello, me pregunto: ¿qué palabra castellana podemos utilizar para designar *scope* en el contexto dado por estos ejemplos?

> El *scope* de esta reunión es designar los portavoces
>
> Scope of Trump's falsehoods unprecedented for a modern presidential candidate (sacado de [una noticia](http://www.latimes.com/politics/la-na-pol-trump-false-statements-20160925-snap-story.html))

A mí **alcance** me parece la palabra más cercana, pero no sé si atino.

Comment: Para el significado 1, *alcance* me parece a mí también la mejor opción (tu segundo ejemplo); para el significado 5, y tu primer ejemplo, usaría *objeto* u *objetivo*. Significados distintos, aunque estén relacionados, pueden requerir palabras distintas en otro idioma.

Comment: @Gorpik si, *alcance* sería la mejor traducción - diría que es una traducción literal que funciona en la mayoría de los casos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

¡Qué difícil dar una respuesta *documentada*!

Tu intuición me parece correcta. Yo también usaría **alcance**, y en algunos contextos ***ámbito***. Tal como señala Gorpik, *objeto* y *objetivo* también calzan con la acepción de *aim or purpose* (5ª acepción).

Una excelente herramienta para saber la opinión simultánea de muchos traductores *de oficio* es [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish). Ahí puedes ver las distintas alternativas usadas para [traducir *scope*](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=scope), cada una en su contexto en inglés y castellano. Me parece que ahí se confirma que **alcance** es el favorito indiscutido, con algunas menciones de **ámbito**, y con la de ***finalidad*** para el sentido de la 5ª acepción.

Comment: Great job, couldn't recall **ámbito**

Answer (score 2):

*Alcance* sería la traducción más acertada de *scope*. No obstante, *extensión* (extension) podría utilizarse en algunos casos en sustitución de alcance:

> The current scope of these problems
>
> La extensión actual de estos problemas

Hablando de *problemas* yo utilizaría el verbo *extenderse* en vez de *alcanzar*.

Diría que "los problemas se extienden" y no que "los problemas alcanzan".